# pgf Error: Arrow end type ``latex''' unknown

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfiles

The following document:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em},
tmp/.style  = {coordinate}, 
sum/.style= {draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm},
input/.style = {coordinate},
output/.style= {coordinate},
pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}}
}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex',every node/.style={transform shape}]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\large]
    \node [input, name=rinput] (rinput) {};
    \node [sum, right of=rinput] (sum1) {-};  
    \draw [->] (rinput) -- node{$\beta_c$} (sum1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Works fine. Now, I have a parent document of class book, and a child document (/subfile). If I put the above figure code (whether directly or using subfile) in the parent, it works fine. If I put it in the child, it give me errors:

```
Package pgf Error: Arrow end type ``latex''' unknown. ...tex',every node/.style={transform shape}]
Package pgf Error: Arrow end type ``latex''' unknown. ...tex',every node/.style={transform shape}]
Package pgf Error: Arrow end type ``latex''' unknown. ...tex',every node/.style={transform shape}]
Package pgf Error: Arrow end type ``latex''' unknown. ...tex',every node/.style={transform shape}]
Package pgf Error: Arrow end type ``tikze@>>@latex''' unknown. ...tex',every node/.style={transform shape}]
Package pgf Error: Arrow end type ``tikze@>@latex''' unknown. \draw [->]
Cannot patch \document,(auxhook) using \AtBeginDocument instead.
Unused global option(s): [english].
Overfull \hbox (13.70734pt too wide) in paragraph
Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `\textenglish'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `\phi'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
Font shape `EU1/SimplifiedArabic(0)/m/sl' undefined(Font) using `EU1/SimplifiedArabic(0)/m/n' instead
\headheight is too small (12.0pt): Make it at least 13.9141pt.
Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `\textenglish'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `\chi'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
Underfull \vbox (badness 1895) has occurred while \output is active []
\headheight is too small (12.0pt): Make it at least 13.9141pt.
Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `\textenglish'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `\beta'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
\headheight is too small (12.0pt): Make it at least 13.9141pt.
\headheight is too small (12.0pt): Make it at least 13.9141pt.
Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

Comment: How do you call the subfile from main file? What lines from your example are included in subfile? Do you include `usetikzlibrary{arrows}` in main file? ...

Comment: Yes, that is what was missing. But why it only matters if it is within the child file but does not matter if it is within the parent file?

Comment: I cannot answer until you explain how is your main file and what's lines from your example are in subfile and how mainfile calls subfile but if your subfile only includes the figure, all libraries and packages needed for subfiles should be included in mainfiles.

Comment: Anyway, if you want you can put an answer and I will mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't know which kind of `subfile` are you using (`standalone`, `subfiles` ?) but your example shows some possible discrepancies between `main file` preamble and `child file` one. In fact, it looks like `shapes`, `arrows` and `positioning` libraries are only loaded when compiling the child document. If you include them in `main` preamble you'll solve the problem.